# How to sync media playback on two devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using following method of class AVPlayer.h in my project.

```
- (void)setRate:(float)rate time:(CMTime)itemTime atHostTime:(CMTime)hostClockTime
```

Acording to [AVPlayer.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVPlayer) documentation, this method can be used to sync playback on two devices provided host time of one device..

I have given all "time" possibilities that I could give as params in itemTime and hostClockTime, but the playback has been never synched.. In-fact, AVPlayer doesn't play media items..

Any help would be highly appreciated from the persons who have used this method for synching as well as any-other mechanism for synching media playback on iOS devices.

Thanks in advance..